# Which is the best way to modify CodeIgniter Cart?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

as we know, CI Cart is not giving functionality to modify cart product options (except qty).

So, I am having two options : 
extend the CI Cart like this (https://bitbucket.org/nelson.wells/extended-codeigniter-cart/src)

OR

Copy the CI Cart in to array,
derstroy cart,
update array,
add new array in CI Cart.

Which way is better, via aspects of performance and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with an extended class over a "hack" (destroying the cart just to change one attribute) any day.

Performance / error considerations will be nearly irrelevant (unless you're writing buggy code!).  If you're concerned, go with a community-vetted class over writing your own.